# How can I enable Java in Chromium?

Tags: java, chromium

I've got Java working on Firefox in [Ubuntu 11.04](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases#Ubuntu_11.04_.28Natty_Narwhal.29) (Natty Narwhal), but using the same page on [Chromium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromium_%28web_browser%29) tells me Java cannot be found.

How can I enable Java on Chromium in my Ubuntu 11.04?

Comment: Is [Ubuntu restricted extras](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/ubuntu-restricted-extras) Installed ?

Comment: Installed and still no luck.

Comment: Can you try if it's not the specific page you are trying to see is causing the problem? Try other java pages to see if they work.

Answer (score 14):

The first thing to do is to install Java:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre icedtea-7-plugin
```

Restart chromium-browser and then use `about:plugins` to check if it's enabled.

Comment: No need for `openjdk`, `icedtea-*-plugin` is enough

Comment: I have both of those but don't see an option in `about:plugins` to enable it.

Answer (score 12):

- Go to : `about:plugins`
- Under location: you should see enable (if it is disabled).

[image: Java Plugin]

This happened with me at first.

Also, see: [Do I have Java?](http://www.java.com/en/download/installed.jsp)
If it takes too long , it means that there isn't java installed or something went wrong during installation.

Answer (score 4):

According to [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/450929/12518)

> You can't. You would have to recompile Chromium and edit the line that disallows NPAPI.

Answer (score 1):

You get the IcedTea-web Java browser plugin by installing the **icedtea-plugin** package.

You can quickly do this from the command line running:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install icedtea-plugin
```