# Java is not working on some websites

Tags: java, chromium

I have `icedtea6-plugin` installed on my Ubuntu box. The weird thing is, when I am browsing the internet, certain websites are able to use Java and some websites don't. For instance, I am able to log in to my bank at http://www.nordea.dk/ ; they use a Java applet to authenticate the user.

But when I try to use http://keepvid.com/; it says `Loading Java Applet`. And then after a minute or two it says:

`Error: Please click here to download Java, If you already have Java, please restart your browser and try again.`

I've tried to restart my computer, closed and opened Chromium Browser. But it didn't work also.

Could someone please point me in the right direction to solve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Does this happen on any other browser?

Comment: See this question maybe you have the same issue : http://askubuntu.com/questions/47240/how-can-i-enable-java-in-chromium

Comment: @Roland I have only chromium installed. And this problem definitely exists in chromium.

Comment: @binarylife I tried the suggestions on that page. The "Do I have java" link says I do have java albeit an older version. I am using openjdk-6-jre 6b22-1.10. And my "about:plugins" page says that the icedtea-web plugin is enabled.

Comment: @Jay I don't think you understood the purpose of my comment :).  
I want you to tell us if it works on another broswer so we can help to determine what is causing the problem (for example if it is chromium's problem alone).

Comment: @Roland Maybe I did not make myself clear the first time. But what I was saying was that, I do not have any other browser other than chromium installed on my box. So I do not know if this problem exists on any other browser like firefox for example. But I can install firefox and test it out if it helps...

Comment: @Jay: Then True, you have Java. So now try installing another browser and see as Roland Taylor suggested.

Comment: @binarylife I installed firefox. Keepvid works perfectly in firefox with the same Java installation. Nordea.dk also works perfectly in firefox. So it seems like the problem is only with chromium.

Comment: Try waiting a few minutes... After some googling I found out that it just doesn't show the loading progress.

Comment: @nickguletskii After a few minutes it only shows this message -> "Error: Please click here to download Java, If you already have Java, please restart your browser and try again." And after that, nothing happens.

Comment: @nickguletskii Okay, I'll try it right now. Any idea, how long I might have to wait?

Comment: @Jay Tried it myself, seems that this applet has something weird about it.

Comment: @nickguletskii Its not just the applet on [link](keepvid.com). [link](tubegrip.com) does not work either.

Comment: @Jay That is because they use the same applet ;)

Comment: So is there anyways, I can solve this issue?

Comment: Am i allowed to make bumps?

Comment: At least could someone please tell me, if its a problem with chromium or a problem with the Java applet on those aforementioned websites?

Comment: @Jay: Are you still having this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Try installing the Oracle Java some applications only work with it.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Java

Answer (score 0):

keepvid is looking for a plugin that supports `application/x-java-jnlp-file`. This may be, [according to wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Web_Start), the Java Network Launching Protocol, that is, Java Web Start.

The JWS for IcedTea appears to be provided separately (this is *not* "java web plugin", it's a different thing Sun once made), in the [icedtea-netx](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/oneiric/+package/icedtea-netx) package

Answer (score 0):

This article is useful if you need help getting the Java plugin work with an Oracle installation: [How to install the Java plugin in Ubuntu for Chrome and Firefox](http://technonstop.com/install-java-plugin-ubuntu-linux)

Comment: Would you mind to explain, why one should follow your link?

Answer (score 0):

Try installing Java Software Developer Kit (JDK). Look Below 
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html
Perhaps will work.

Comment: JDK (Java Developer Kit) is not the same as JRE (Java Runtime Environment). Installing JDK won't make a difference.