# Flash and Java plug-ins in Chromium lost after upgrade to 14.04

Tags: java, flash, 14.04, chromium, plugins

I've just upgraded 12.04 to 14.04. Java and flash plug-ins are lost from Chromium. I have Openjdk7 installed with Icedtea and adobe flash plug-in for Firefox.

```
sudo cp /usr/lib/flashplugin-installer/libflashplayer.so /usr/lib/chromium-browser/plugins
```

The above command didn't help!

- Can anyone help me out in setting the plugins.

Answer (score 8):

The Chromium maintainer [announced](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-desktop/2014-April/004462.html) that Chromium is going to experience 'growing pains'.  Several things will be breaking.

Regarding flash, you will need to install the pepper flash plugin instead

```
sudo apt-get install pepperflashplugin-nonfree 
sudo update-pepperflashplugin-nonfree --install
```

Comment: Can you help in the case of java plugin in browser

Comment: See if [this helps](http://askubuntu.com/questions/47240/how-can-i-enable-java-in-chromium)

Comment: i have icedtea-7-plugin installed already with openjdk-7-jre

Comment: Java (IcedTea) doesn't have a PPAPI plugin available, and so it's not usable in Chromium.

Answer (score 3):

Give the Pepper Flash Player for Chromium a try:

`sudo apt-get install pepperflashplugin-nonfree`