# java plugin in Chromium

Tags: java, chromium, plugins, icedtea

Icedtea-7-plugin installed but it does not appears in the list in about:plugins in Chromium.

Not able to execute java applets.

Tried installing Icedtea-7-plugin but in vain.
Using openjdk7 in 14.04

Answer (score 22):

Java (IcedTea) doesn't have a PPAPI plugin available, and so it's not usable in Chromium, since Chromium 34 in Trusty has switched to the Aura rendering framework and no longer allows NPAPI plugins. See also https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bug/1308783.

Comment: So? How to run java applets in Chromium and Ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: You can't. You would have to recompile Chromium and edit the line that disallows NPAPI.

Comment: From your answer I understand that chromium is not a standard browser for Ubuntu 14.4. Better to remove it.

Comment: It's standard in that it is included in the Ubuntu repos.

Comment: What's the value today for a browser not capable to run java?

Comment: Well, I haven't had to run Java within my browser in a long time, and there are general vulnerabilities with running Java web applets...

Comment: @Fabio Agree Fabio, we're talking about [Java not Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/a/245068/563329). Javascript is everywhere, Java is reserved only for a few sites that want to run some applet written long ago. ([eg](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/Curriculum/Probability/Buffon.shtml))

Comment: @isomorphismes Are you kidding? Java is the standard environment to run web browser applications in every company or enterprise? We run at least 5 different Tomcat applications (which requires a Java-enabled browser) in my company! We cannot use Chromium in Ubuntu.

Comment: @Fabio Ah ok. I didn't realise you meant enterprise. I was just talking about web browsing in the great external 'net.

Comment: Java is still a lot used for internet banking, at least in my country...

Comment: @gustavohenke, "a lot" as in "there's is one nasty bank that insists on using Java on its login process", right? :D The only problem is that it happens to be the largest bank in Brazil (which prides itself in running Linux in their ATMs and office computers, BTW). :-/

Comment: I wish one day people who don't have an answer could just remain silent instead of speculating whether someone does or doesn't need what they're asking for...