# Is actual version of Chromium browser (34.0.1847.116) compatible with Oracle Java 7 browser plugin?

Tags: java, chromium, plugins, oracle

I can not make it work nor find an official confirmation of compatibility. Oracle Java 7 plugin works fine with Firefox but fresh Chromium browser installation does not even list it at chrome://plugins

Comment: You can have both Java 7 and 6 if it doens't work.

Comment: Do you know if Oracle's Java (version is nearly irrelevant) ships with a PPAPI plugin? See also http://askubuntu.com/questions/450683/java-plugin-in-chromium.

Comment: @saiarcot895 , you are right - looks like Linux NPAPI support is completely [dropped from this version on](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!msg/chromium-dev/xEbgvWE7wMk/D_07G2lftacJ) and Oracle hasn't released an PPAPI plugin implementation at the moment.

Comment: @zgb: Actually, the official release of Aura (and the deprecation of NPAPI) was pushed back to M35. Aura was voluntarily turned on in Ubuntu Trusty's Chromium 34, and so NPAPI support was removed. (Aura and NPAPI deprecation were made to be directly linked.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They've dropped NPAPI plugin support in the latest version of Chromium, which means that it can't use the Firefox version of Flash or Java, which is also an NPAPI plugin. It does support PPAPI plugins, though. Flash has a PPAPI version, but Java doesn't, yet.

Chrome browser (not Chromium) still supports NPAPI, though. You can use Oracle Java and flashplugin-installer with it just like you can with Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

Linux NPAPI support is dropped in this and future versions of Chromium, it's not possible to install Java browser plugin until PPAPI implementation of Java plugin is released by Oracle or third party.

Current version of NPAPI Oracle Java plugin can be used in Firefox at the moment and that is the only alternative I have found so far.